# Analyzing data with multiple treatment layers

Tags: anova

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I'm having some trouble figuring out the best way to approach analyzing my data. I have a study where we investigated the effects of different dietary components on shelf life parameters over time. However, I'm facing some challenges with analyzing the data using a RM Anova. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to proceed.

In our study, we have two snacks containing one of two ingredients, which I'll refer to as "Ingredient A" and "Ingredient B." From there, we split these two main snack groups further and coated them with one of 5 additional treatments. We then further took these now 10 groups and split them into two, putting them in one of two different storage conditions (20 different treatments altogether).

In my model, I want to investigate the main effects of ingredient, coating, and storage condition, as well as their interactions over time. However, I keep getting an error "Mixed model has saturated mean and profiled variance. Fit does not proceed" when I model it with proc glimmix in SAS.

proc glimmix data=work.shelf;
class ID snack coat storage time;
model pv = snack|coat|storage|time / DDFM=KR;
random *residual* / subject=ID type=cs;

Where ID is each snack x coating x storage (as each would be tested over time).

I've never had a data set with more than one "layer" of treatment, and am wondering if I'm approaching this correctly, due to the hierarchal nature of the treatments. My understanding is that I don't need to nest the effects within my model, as the 5 treatments and 2 storage conditions are the same for the two ingredient types.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Do you have multiple observations 20 experimental conditions? I gather you assessed them multiple times over times, but did you have multiple items for each of the conditions? And I assume pv is some continuous variable that has some randomly varying (most of the time non-zero) values even if everything is perfectly preserved (something like number of bacteria might need a different treatment, if it is initially usually zero)?

Comment: Yes, sorry PV is a continuous outcome, and is always above 0. I have 3 observations for each of the 20 conditions.

Comment: Maybe your ID variable is not correctly coded then? Does it have 60 different values, i.e. differ for the 3 observations for the 20 conditions, but the same for the same item observed over time?

Comment: Yes, that is how I currently have it coded